# hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create not clearing out existing data

Tags: hibernate, integration-testing

I am using

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
```

in my **persistence.xml** for my integration test, and when I run the integration test, I get

```
ERROR SchemaExport:386 - Unsuccessful: create table tableName ...
ERROR SchemaExport:387 - Table 'tableName' already exists
```

but isn't **hbm2ddl.auto=create** supposed to replace the table if it already exists?  Why would I be getting this error?

By the way, this was working as expected last week, so I'm really confused about why I'd be getting this error all of a sudden.

Comment: What changed?  Things don't magically stop working.  Did the account under which the Hibernate runs change?

Comment: @AaronSheffey I can't think of anything that changed.  The credientials to connect to the database didn't change, neither did the persistence unit.  I just now manually dropped and recreated the schema, and now it works again as expected, but I still want to know what happened because this has happened once before and the fact that I'm having to manually drop and recreate the schema from time to time must be a symptom of a deeper problem.

Comment: why not use create-drop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up manually writing and executing SQL statements to drop and recreate the schema, and then it worked again as expected.  I never did figure out why Hibernate wouldn't drop and recreate the existing tables, and it hasn't happened again since.

Answer (score 0):

This error confuse me first time. But solution is quite simple. Just change in your hibernate.cfg.xml this option:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```

to

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

Comment: I didn't want to update the schema, I wanted to create it anew with each build.  So, this answer does not address my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The behavour changed in Hibernate 3.7 and was reverted back in 4.x I assume, see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6384.